# Не работает @bot.callback_query_handler

Tags: python, telebot, callback

Делаю своего первого ТГ-бота. Возникла проблема в том, что функция-декоратор callback_query_handler не запускается, хотя кнопки бот выводит и пользователь может на них нажать.

Делаю как в примерах: там при написании такого же кода результат имеется, у меня наоборот - нет, хотя коды идентичны.

Помогите, пожалуйста

```
from telebot import types
from loader import bot
import time

current_year = time.localtime().tm_year
year = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)

btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(current_year, callback_data='btn1')
btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(current_year + 1, callback_data='btn2')
year.add(btn1, btn2)
print('Кнопки сделаны')


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def check_callback(callback):
    if callback.data == 'btn1':
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, f'Вы выбрали год {current_year}')
    elif callback.data == 'btn2':
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, f'Вы выбрали год {current_year + 1}')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо call: True необходимо было указать callback: True